# Why authenticated does not work when refreshing the page - Angular 5

Tags: angular

Why authenticated does not work when refreshing the page ? When the user is logged in. After the page is refreshed, the user is logged out.

auth/auth.service.ts:

```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
    import {Router} from '@angular/router';
    import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
    import {User} from './user';
    import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response} from '@angular/http';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
    import {AppComponent} from '../app.component';
    import {Observable} from 'rxjs/';
    import {JwtHelperService} from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

    @Injectable()

    export class AuthService {

      private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
      private loggedUser = new BehaviorSubject<User>(<User>{});
      private loggedPassword = new BehaviorSubject<User>(<User>{});
      result: any;

      _loggedIn: boolean;


      get isLoggedIn() {
        return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
      }

      constructor(private router: Router, private _http: Http, public jwtHelperService: JwtHelperService) {

      }


      login(user: User) {
        this.getUsers().subscribe(data => {

          for (const it of data) {

            if (user.userName === it.name && user.password === it.password) {

              this._loggedIn = true;
              this.loggedIn.next(true);
              this.loggedUser.next(user);
              this.loggedPassword.next(user);
              this.router.navigate(['/']);              

            }
          }
        });
      }

      registration(newUser: User): Promise<User> {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);

        return this._http.post('/api/users', newUser)
          .toPromise()
          .then(response => response.json().data as User); // .data as User

      }      

      getUsers() { 

        return this._http.get('/api/users').map(result => this.result = result.json().data);
      }


      public isAuthenticated(): boolean {

        const token = localStorage.getItem('token');


         if (!token) {
          return false;
        } else {
          return true; // !this.jwtHelperService.isTokenExpired(token);
        }

      }


      /*

        logout() {
          this.loggedIn.next(false);
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
      */
    }
```

auth/auth.guard.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  Router
} from '@angular/router';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}


  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn
      .take(1)
      .map((isLoggedIn: boolean) => {
        if (!isLoggedIn && !this.authService.isAuthenticated()) { 

          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
          return false;
        }
        return true;
      });
  }
}
```

What features do I miss in my code?

Should I call the **isAuthenticated()** method in the **login()** method?

Is the value **token** correctly returned in the **isAuthenticated()** method?

Comment: where do you set the token in the localstorage?

Comment: Alexander , in method login()

Comment: I don't see that code in the login method

Comment: @Alexander the last post is my code

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to get the auth token from local storage, but your login() method never puts it into local storage.

So, when you reload, the auth token that was only in memory disappears, and it's not in local storage either.

Answer (score 0):

in method login() but the user is logged out after refreshing the page:

```
login(user: User) {
 this.getUsers().subscribe(data => {

  for (const it of data) {

    if (user.userName === it.name && user.password === it.password) {        
      this._loggedIn = true;
      this.loggedIn.next(true);
      this.loggedUser.next(user);
      this.loggedPassword.next(user);
      this.router.navigate(['/']);  // login
      console.log('loggedIn.value : ');
      console.log(this.loggedIn.value);
         localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(user));

    }
  }
});
```

All the time is 'token true'. Even if the user has not logged in yet

Answer (score 0):

I would like to do that the logged in user, after refreshing the page, has not been logged out.

my code:

app.modules.ts:

```
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';

import {AppRoutingModule} from './app-routing.module';
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from '@angular/forms';

import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';

import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {AppMaterialModule} from './app-material/app-material.module';

import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {AboutComponent} from './about/about.component';
import {AuthService} from './auth/auth.service';
import {AuthGuard} from './auth/auth.guard';

import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http';
import './rxjs-operators';
import {RegistrationComponent} from './registration/registration.component';

import { JwtModule } from '@auth0/angular-jwt';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,     // plik app.component.ts
    HomeComponent,    // plik home.component.ts
    AboutComponent,
    LoginComponent,   // plik login.component.ts
    RegistrationComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppMaterialModule,
    FormsModule,      // dodane z prjketu ng5
    HttpModule /* ,
       JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {
        tokenGetter: () => {
          return localStorage.getItem('token');
        },
        whitelistedDomains: ['/login']
      }
    }) */
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, AuthGuard],
 //  schemas: [CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA, NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

app.component.ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {AuthService} from './auth/auth.service';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

  title = 'app';
  users: Array<any>;
  _loggedIn: boolean;

  constructor(private _data: AuthService) {


    this._data.isLoggedIn.subscribe(data => {
        this._loggedIn = data.valueOf();

    });


    this._data.getUsers()
      .subscribe(res => {
        this.users = res;           
      });

  } 
}
```

app.component.html:

```
<ul>
  <li><a routerLink="">Home</a></li>
  <li><a routerLink="about">About</a></li>
    <li><a *ngIf="!_loggedIn; else registration" routerLink="login">Login</a></li> 
     <ng-template #registration><li><a  routerLink="registration">Registration</a></li>
     <!--    <button md-button (click)="onLogout()">Logout</button> -->
     </ng-template>
</ul>
{{_loggedIn}}<p>

</p>     

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

it works, as is logged in user displays the **Registration** button. After refreshing the page the variable **_loggedIn** is equal to **false**

app.routing.modules.ts:

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes, RouterModule} from '@angular/router';

import {AuthGuard} from './auth/auth.guard';
import {AboutComponent} from './about/about.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './login/login.component';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {RegistrationComponent} from './registration/registration.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    component: HomeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }, {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent 
  }, {
    path: 'registration',
    component: RegistrationComponent
  }, {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent 
  }
];


@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

login.component.ts:

```
import {AuthService} from './../auth/auth.service';
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import {FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators} from '@angular/forms';
import {AppComponent} from '../app.component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private authService: AuthService
  ) {
      this.authService._loggedIn = false;
  }

  ngOnInit() {}

  onSubmit() {
      this.authService.login(this.form.value );
  }
}
```

login.componet.ts:

```
        <form class="example-form" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <p>Please login to continue</p>             


                User * <input matInput formControlName="userName" required>

        <br />
                Password * <input matInput type="password" formControlName="password" required>    


                <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">Login</button>              

        </form>
```

auth/auth.component.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {Router} from '@angular/router';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
import {User} from './user';
import {Http, Headers, RequestOptions, Response} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';
import {AppComponent} from '../app.component';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/';



// import {JwtHelperService} from '@auth0/angular-jwt';



@Injectable()


export class AuthService {


  private loggedIn = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
  private loggedUser = new BehaviorSubject<User>(<User>{});
  private loggedPassword = new BehaviorSubject<User>(<User>{});
  result: any;

  _loggedIn: boolean;

  get isLoggedIn() {
    return this.loggedIn.asObservable();
  }
  // , public jwtHelperService: JwtHelperService

  constructor(private router: Router, private _http: Http) { }

  login(user: User) {
    this.getUsers().subscribe(data => {

      for (const it of data) {

        if (user.userName === it.name && user.password === it.password) {

        localStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(user));

          this._loggedIn = true;
          this.loggedIn.next(true);
          this.loggedUser.next(user);
          this.loggedPassword.next(user);
          this.router.navigate(['/']);  

        }
      }
    });
  }


  getUsers() { 
    return this._http.get('/api/users').map(result => this.result = result.json().data);
  }


  public isAuthenticated(): boolean {

    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    // const token: string = this.jwtHelperService.tokenGetter();

    if (!token) {
      return false;
    } else {
      return true; // !this.jwtHelperService.isTokenExpired(token);
    }
  }
}
```

I do not know if the **if** statement should return **false** or **true** here

auth/auth.guard.ts:

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {
  CanActivate,
  ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
  RouterStateSnapshot,
  Router
} from '@angular/router';
import {AuthService} from './auth.service';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean {
    if (!this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
      this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

should I delete the **token** here?  **localStorage.removeItem('token');**